# Adding a dropdown list from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this following code :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd_SubCategory" Width="160px" runat="server" DataTextField="CATEGORY_NAME" DataValueField="CATEGORY_ID"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
<br />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_SubCatg" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

<asp:ImageButton ID="Ib_AddSubCategory" runat="server" OnClick="Ib_AddSubCategory_Click" ImageUrl="/images/add.gif" />

 protected void Ib_AddSubCategory_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string SelectedCategory="";
    if (ctrl_list.Count == 0)
        SelectedCategory = dd_SubCategory.SelectedValue;
    else
        SelectedCategory = Session["Selected_SubCatg"] != null && Session["Selected_SubCatg"].ToString()!=""?Session["Selected_SubCatg"].ToString():((DropDownList)ctrl_list[ctrl_list.Count - 1]).SelectedValue;
    try
    {


        DataRow[] Rows = DataHelper.TicketCategories.Select("PARENT_CATEGORY_ID='" + SelectedCategory + "'");

        if (Rows.Length > 0)
        {
            AddSubCategory(Rows);

        }
        foreach (Control item in ctrl_list)
            pnl_SubCatg.Controls.Add(item);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }


}
 List<Control> _ctrl_list = null;
List<Control> ctrl_list {
    get
    {
        if (Session["SUB_CATG_LIST"] == null)
        {
            _ctrl_list = new List<Control>();
            Session["SUB_CATG_LIST"] = _ctrl_list;
        }
        return Session["SUB_CATG_LIST"] as List<Control>;
    }
}
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["SUB_CATG_LIST"] = null;
        Session["Selected_SubCatg"] = null;
    }
    if (ctrl_list.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Control item in ctrl_list)
            pnl_SubCatg.Controls.Add(item);
    }
 }
  private void AddSubCategory(DataRow [] Rows)
{

    DropDownList dd_SubCategory1 = new DropDownList();
    dd_SubCategory1.Width = Unit.Pixel(160);
    dd_SubCategory1.DataTextField = "CATEGORY_NAME";
    dd_SubCategory1.DataValueField = "CATEGORY_ID";
    dd_SubCategory1.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    dd_SubCategory1.DataSource = Rows.CopyToDataTable();
    dd_SubCategory1.DataBind();
    dd_SubCategory1.SelectedIndexChanged += dd_SubCategory1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    dd_SubCategory1.AutoPostBack = true;
    ctrl_list.Add(dd_SubCategory1);

}

void dd_SubCategory1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Selected_SubCatg"] = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;

}
```

i am trying to add a dropdown list containing the subcategories of the last inserted dropdown list , my problem is `dd_SubCategory1_SelectedIndexChanged` is not firing and i can't get the and the `selectedValue` of the last `dropdownlist` is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because its dynamically generated and it will lose its state after its rendered on your page.

To access the dropdown and its related events and properties, you will need to recreate it everytime your page is postback.

Hope its clear enough.

Comment: but i did that on the page_load event : if (ctrl_list.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Control item in ctrl_list)
            pnl_SubCatg.Controls.Add(item);
    }

Comment: You will need to reuse the code that you used for creating that dropdown programmatically AGAIN when your page is postback before you start manipulating with that dropdown. Only then your event will get fired.

Comment: Page_load is not where you need to generate this, if you want it to persist across postback and maintain selection then you need to do this on OnInit.  hope this helps